# How To trigger http url on laravel controller

Tags: laravel, http

I am trying to build a sms notification using laravel,
I want to execute a http url once i hit the function on a laravel's controller with this code

```
public function sendSMS()
    {
         return 'https://api.smsglobal.com/http-api.php?action=sendsms&user=testuser&password=secret&from=Test&to=61447100250&text=Hello%20world'
    }
```

Am expecting this to execute the url to send the sms notification but with no avail, it will be a great if someone will help me on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

From the small snippet of code provided, you are purely returning the string of the URL to be used. You would need to use something like [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) or [Laravel's HTTP Client](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#request-data) for completing the actual request.

In this case, SMSGlobal also have their own [PHP Client](https://github.com/smsglobal/smsglobal-php) which you may use for this purpose, which can be installed by running the following command:

```
composer require smsglobal/smsglobal-php
```

The following is an example of the process to send an SMS, taken from their [github page](https://github.com/smsglobal/smsglobal-php), which can be modified to suit your purpose:

```
// get your REST API keys from MXT https://mxt.smsglobal.com/integrations
\SMSGlobal\Credentials::set('YOUR_API_KEY', 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY');

$sms = new \SMSGlobal\Resource\Sms();

try {
    $response = $sms->sendToOne('DESTINATION_NUMBER', 'This is a test message.');
    print_r($response['messages']);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the replay, do you have any sample codes for cURL or Guzzle to trigger the http?